# If I want to stream videos with multiple dubbings, do I need to store separate video file for each dubbing, or can I merge them while piping buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, video-streaming, nodejs-stream

I want to stream video using node js. If I want to include multiple dubbings, do I need to store separate video file for each dubbing, or can I merge them in runtime.

If I can merge it while streaming, what package do I need?

Comment: **(1) Not enough useful info**.... For example: What video file format is being used here? Does "streaming" mean _"generate a live stream"_ or it means _"play a stored file"_? Is this a question about **audio** but it never once mentions that keyword (or is "video dubbing" some kind of new thing)?... If doing **audio** dubbing for video, then you simply store one video but with multiple audio files of these different "dubs" (MP3 format is easiest to slice since it is just a joined sequence of audio frames).

Comment: **(2)** I don't use NodeJS so I cannot recommend a package (but you can Google search for such options). All I can help you with is: using Javascript for handling MPEG audio/video bytes if you're willing to write your own code for that. You must be able to use arrays and understand some hex or bytes editing.